# Streaming HLS/m3u8 in Android native player starting with lowest bitrate

Tags: android, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

the Android native player will always start with the highest bitrate available and then decide to either downshift to lower bitrate (if the network is bad) or stay at that bitrate itself. Because of this the video starts late in low internet connections. 
Can we change the default structure and start streaming with lowest bitrate stream like iOS ?

Comment: You can go through vitamino library for this check its documentation.one downside is only that it will increase your apk size.

Comment: @JayShah Thanks for the reply. I tried Vitamio but it didnt work for me. It was giving a error code -1094995529 . https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/issues/372

Comment: @JayShah Also, can we tweak something in Android Native player. Was avoiding to use a third party player for that.

Answer (score 1):

The native VideoView doesnt have support for adaptive streaming.

Option is to build a custom player using ExoPlayer
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

I used a library which is a wrapper around ExoPlayer.
https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia

Works great!